# how to check values while using recursion in yacc?

Tags: yacc, lex

I am using recursion in yacc and I want to check all the values that are parsed by the recursion rule.My yacc rule is

```
%{

#include<stdio.h>

.

.

.

%}

%%

abc:ABC expr

;

expr:VALUE','expr

|VALUE

;


%%
```

if i have a statement like

```
ABC 1,2,3,4
```

it gets parsed.
i want to check that all the numbers parsed via **expr**
have sum equal to some value say 10
how can i check this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

You can count the values parsed and keep their running total with code that goes something like this:

```
%{

#include<stdio.h>
int count;

.

.

.

%}

%%

abc: { count = 0; } ABC expr { printf("count: %d; sum: %d\n", count, $2); }

;

expr: VALUE ',' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }

| VALUE { $$ = $1; count++; }

;


%%
```

Comment: and how can i count the number of values? like in this case i have 4 values that are being parsed.